# How to repair Vista after broken SP1 install

Tags: windows-vista, installation, troubleshooting

I tried installing Vista SP1 and now my computer won't boot up in Safe Mode, let alone any other config. How can I roll back the changes to the OS?

Extra info: it freezes after loading crcdisk.sys - there are a lot of forums I found that are full of "me too" answers; couldn't find an actual answer.

Comment: Have you tried System Restore?

Comment: Yeah, the restore point didn't work, it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use system restore by booting from a Vista DVD

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial142.html

You may also have the Windows Recovery Environment on the hard drive, use F8 at the start of boot when you see the bios load the splash screen, this will get you the Windows Advanced Boot Options, see if there is a "repair your computer" option, if there is, select that.

.
[image]